# Magento 1.9.3.2 compiling CSS

Tags: magento-1.9.3.2, scss

I'm a front-end developer and have been given a Magento website (version 1.9.3.2 CE) to work on.

I'm relatively new to Magento and have spent the day researching but I can't seem to find the answer to my question.

Is it possible to compile sass files on the server? Or do I need a local version of the website in order to compile the files with Compass? I've got SFTP/ssh access and there's currently no version control set up so I'd need to set the website up from scratch on Git.

In this case, is it best just to create a static css file to overwrite the current styles?

Thanks so much in advance!